# Assign Arrays as Array Elements to a PHP's Class Variable/Property

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my code =>

```
class Dbhead{

public static $category=array(
"id"=>"Id",
"title"=>"Title",
"code"=>"Code",
"description"=>"Description",
"remarks"=>"Remarks"
);

public static $client=array(
"id"=>"Id",
"title"=>"Title",
"name"=>"Name",
"mobile"=>"Mobile",
"address"=>"Address",
"remarks"=>"Remarks"
);

    public $allfields=array(
        "client"=>self::$client,
        "category"=>self::$category
    );
}
```

Assigning `$client` & `$category` arrays to `$allfields` as elements breaks the code.
I have tried changing `$client` & `$category` to public only.

I have tried all the possible ways I knew to achieve it except doing it using method/function as I do not want that.

Comment: Do it in your `__construct()` method.

Comment: From the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) `This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.`..... ie, you can't.... you have to define something dynamic like this in a method

Comment: @Julien I do not want to use any method. I am seeking alternate. `__construct()` is a magic wand. I am trying this as it is my transition time from procedural to OOP.

Comment: If these values aren't changed in your code, then you can use constants - https://3v4l.org/aS4nN

Comment: @MarkBaker Your answer is convincing but I find PHP flexible enough to do the stuffs my way.

Comment: I was thinking if it could be a good practice to keep the variables outside the class in the same file. As the class file will be automatically included using `__autoloader()` equivalents these variables will be available parallel to the Dbhead class properties.

Comment: @MarkBaker I am using this to generate form dynamically from validation on client/server side to handling the database. So `const` thing solved my problem. As your answer is a comment, how can I +1 it?

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank You. I am unable to access the values mapped with key in the arrays as `constant("Dbhead::const_table=>$key")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The [manual says so](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

As a work-around you can do this:

```
class Dbhead
{
    public static $category = [
        "id"          => "Id",
        "title"       => "Title",
        "code"        => "Code",
        "description" => "Description",
        "remarks"     => "Remarks",
    ];

    public static $client = [
        "id"      => "Id",
        "title"   => "Title",
        "name"    => "Name",
        "mobile"  => "Mobile",
        "address" => "Address",
        "remarks" => "Remarks",
    ];

    public static $allfields;

    // Arguably not the most elegant way to solve the problem
    // Since this is a setter without an argument
    public static function setClient()
    {
        static::$allfields['client'] = static::$client;
    }

    public static function setCategory()
    {
        static::$allfields['category'] = static::$category;
    }
}
```

Or non static stuff. You can mix static and non-static but hey, it's not that great.

```
class DbHead{
    protected $category, $client, $allFields;

    public function __construct(array $category,array $client)
    {
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->client = $client;

        $this->allFields['client'] = $client;
        $this->allFields['category'] = $category;
    }

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    public function getAllFields()
    {
        return $this->allFields;
    }

    // Alternatively provide setters for each field in particular
    // If you don't wish to initialize the values on class instantiation

    public function setCategory(array $category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }
    public function setClient(array $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        return $this;
    }

    public function createAllFields()
    {
        $this->allFields['client'] = $this->client;
        $this->allFields['category'] = $this->category;
    }
}

$dbHead = new DbHead([
    "id"          => "Id",
    "title"       => "Title",
    "code"        => "Code",
    "description" => "Description",
    "remarks"     => "Remarks",
], [
    "id"      => "Id",
    "title"   => "Title",
    "name"    => "Name",
    "mobile"  => "Mobile",
    "address" => "Address",
    "remarks" => "Remarks",
]);

$dbHead->createAllFields();
```

Comment: But this is working fine when I was doing this in procedural way or non-OOP way (i. e., without Class).

Comment: Well of course it worked fine in non-OOP, it's just assigning stuff. But if you want to have it in a class you'll have to do it the proper way.

Comment: @andrew Will I need to trigger `setClient()` and `setCategory()` unlike `__construct()`???

Comment: @JulienLachal I am trying to find a way else I will follow you. Lemme try.

Comment: Andrew!  Dude there are more than 20 arrays having more than 20 elements. I wanted to do it with minimum code. @MarkBaker has given me clue using constants.